# How can I correctly code the calculation of the Langevin function? [$y=\text{coth}(x)-\frac{1}{x}$]

Tags: trigonometry, hyperbolic-functions

I am trying to code the Langevin function in C++. The Langevin function is simply:

$y=\text{coth}(x)-\frac{1}{x}$

where $\text{coth}(x) = \frac{e^{2x}+1}{e^{2x}-1}$

I tried coding this in C++ as:

```
inline double coth(double valueIn) {
    double temp = exp(2 * valueIn);
    return (temp + 1) / (temp - 1);
}

inline double langevinFunction(double valueIn) {
    if (valueIn == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return coth(valueIn) - 1 / valueIn;
    }
}
```

This function should put out something close to $y=\text{tanh}(x/3)$.

But it's glitching out. For example, if I put in `langevinFunction(0.0000001)` I get out $-0.00503929$. But the correct value for $\text{coth}(0.0000001)-\frac{1}{0.0000001}$ is $3.5390257835×10^{−8}$ as per Desmos.

Did I screw this up in some way and what did I do wrong if so?

Thanks

**References:**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_functions#Coth

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brillouin_and_Langevin_functions

Comment: The correct caluclation involves the difference between two large but nearly equal numbers.  So Desmos is already pretty inaccurate:  the more exact answer is $$\ell(x) = \tfrac{1}{3} x - \tfrac{1}{45}x^3 + O(x^5)$$ which would yield $0.33333 33333 33331 11111\cdots \times 10^{-8}$.

Are you sure that your implementation is correctly typed in?

Comment: coding theory is for error correcting codes not programming or  computation. removed that tag.

Comment: This seems likely to be a floating point error. As @WADon points out, you are attempting to calculate the difference between two very large but nearly equal numbers. Computers are not so good at that. To calculate the Langevin function of small numbers, I would suggest using the Taylor approximation. For $x$ not too small, your implementation is good.

Comment: On further examination, it seems the method you have used, calculating $\exp(2x)+1$ divided by $\exp(2x)-1$ exacerbates the inaccuracies.  That is because for $x=10^{-7}$ $\exp(2x)-1$ subtracts two numbers close close to 1, losing about half the digits available in a double.  The error build ups further when subtracting the poor estimate for $\coth(x)$, around $10,000$, and $1/x$ equal to $10,000$, and another few figures are lost.  

Direct use of $\coth(x)$ or $\cosh(x)$ and $\sinh(x)$ is an improvement, but better still would be the Taylor series for $\ell(x)$.

Comment: Thanks WA Don. I used the Taylor Series for input below $abs(1)$, then my given `coth(valueIn) - 1 / valueIn;` for values above 1. I notice this approximation (as well as $\frac{cosh(x)}{sinh(x} - 1/x$) both tend to fail when  you start getting to very high input values. I can manage this crudely by limiting the `abs(input)` to ~200 or so, but would you suggest a different approximation yet again for very high input values? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe use a Taylor series for $\ell(1/x)$ - I think one can be developed but I have not tried.